# how to retrieve value from key in side key in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am storing data using model class in firebase project. Please help me how I can retrieve data from key inside key.

[image: Check screenshot]

Check screenshot of data tree.

Comment: You can check the firebase documentation for that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write
Or do you have a problem in particular?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?  Please show us the content of your model class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you need to do that, but this is how I would have approached it. Basically, I add a valueEventListener to my FirebaseDatabase object, I then get the key, which in this case would signify the first level.

Add another FirebaseDatabase reference with the key from the first reference as the child, this will allow you to access the second level key. From there you can go ahead and access the data as you would on a normal value event listener.

Basically, if you call the getData function from the valueEventListener of the classesDatabase reference and pass in your data snapshot, you'll get access to the data on your second level.

```
classesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("classes");

private void getData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String key1 = ds.getKey();
    DatabaseReference dbReference = classesDatabase.child(key1);
        dbReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds2 : dataSnapshot2.getChildren()) {
            String key2 = ds2.getKey();
            Classes classOne = ds2.child(key2).getValue(Classes.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i(getClass().getName().toString(), ": " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}
```